# How can I open a link in new modal window

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I want to create a button or link on a page to open another page in smaller size in modal window without closing the original page

How can I accomplish this the very simple way?
Thank you

**Main page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <a href='site/modal.php'>Click Here to open Modal window</a>
</html>
```

**modal.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <form>
       some input
    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can open a link in a new window with your required size like following. Hope it helps.

```
$('a').click(function() {
    window.open($(this).attr('href'),'title', 'width=800, height=700');
    return false;
});
```

**Update**

You can use this ([jquery-modal](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal)) plugin to show link in a modal like below.

**HTML**

```
<script src="jquery.modal.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.modal.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<a href='site/modal.php'>Click Here to open Modal window</a>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).modal();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I would say that about 99.9% of folks who downvote do not leave a reason. There is a lot of discussion on *Meta* concerning this. My guess is because the OP wants a *modal* window as opposed to a *new* window.